# Libtool Error: Command libtool failed with a nonzero exit code on my pods Xcode project, how do I resolve this error?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

Here is the error in my Xcode console:

**fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file list file: /Users/will/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wash_Up,_Save_Lives-eipyecgydjztztdvvvwuzpdefelh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-Wash Up (No such file or directory)**

I have tried cleaning my build folder, deleting deprived data, and reinstalling cocoa pods, but am still getting this error. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Thank you!